# Extract the indexes of rows that are swapped in order between two files

Tags: bash, awk, diff, file-comparison

I have two large tab-delimited files (>10GB) and I know that when they're sorted, they're identical in content.

However, I'm interested in the order of rows and the index of the swapped ones when they share the same "key" (key here being defined as rows grouped based on `Source` and `Location` columns).

In other words, rows between these two files should be only compared against each other when they come from the same group (i.e. when they share the same Source and Location).

So for example, in the example below, rows 4, 5, 6 from `file1.tsv` should be compared against 4, 5, 6 from `file2.tsv`

*Note: files are normal TSV. Additional spaces are only added here to make columns center- and right-aligned for better visibility. These spaces are not part of the original files*

> file1.tsv

```
     Identifier  Position Source  Location
     AY1:2301        87    ch1        14
    BC1U:4010       105    ch1        14
    AC44:1230        90    ch1        15
    AJC:93410        83    ch1        16
    ABYY:0001       101    ch1        16
       ABC:01        42    ch1        16
      HH:A9CX       413    ch1        17
      LK:9310         2    ch1        17
    JFNE:3410       132    ch1        18
    MKASDL:11        14    ch1        18
   MKDFA:9401        18    ch1        18
  MKASDL1:011       184    ch2        50
   LKOC:AMC02        18    ch2        50
     POI:1100       900    ch2        53
    MCJE:09HA        11    ch2        53
   ABYCI:1123        15    ch2        53
     MNKA:410         1    ch2        53
```

> file2.tsv

```
     Identifier  Position Source  Location
     AY1:2301        87    ch1        14
    BC1U:4010       105    ch1        14
    AC44:1230        90    ch1        15
       ABC:01        42    ch1        16
    ABYY:0001       101    ch1        16
    AJC:93410        83    ch1        16
      HH:A9CX       413    ch1        17
      LK:9310         2    ch1        17
    MKASDL:11        14    ch1        18
    JFNE:3410       132    ch1        18
   MKDFA:9401        18    ch1        18
  MKASDL1:011       184    ch2        50
   LKOC:AMC02        18    ch2        50
     MNKA:410         1    ch2        53
     POI:1100       900    ch2        53
   ABYCI:1123        15    ch2        53
    MCJE:09HA        11    ch2        53
```

I want to do something similar to a "diff" but at the 'group' level (where rows are only compared when they share the same `Source` and `Location`)

I want to extract the **original** "row numbers" when the order of rows are 'swapped' within the same "Source/Location" "*group*" (or key).

The whole row should match in terms of content.

But I have no idea how to go about this. I can only think of writing a for loop which would be extremely inefficient when my original dataset has millions of rows.

Expected result:

```
Group_Source:Location  df1.index  df2.index

ch1:16                         4          6
ch1:16                         6          4
ch1:18                         9         10
ch1:18                        10          9
ch2:53                        14         15
ch2:53                        15         17
ch2:53                        17         14
```

Assumptions:

- Both dataframes have the same number of rows
- Both dataframes are identical (only order of rows are swapped, so if both are sorted by Source, then Location and then Position and then Identifier, then they will be exactly identical)
- 'Swapped' rows always match exactly in terms of content in all columns

Comment: Are the line numbers actually part of the file or did you add them to help us understand the question? If they are not part of the file, please remove them so we know what input we will have.

Comment: No, they're not part of the file, I only added them to illustrate the example I wrote about. Sure, I'll remove them. Thanks.

Comment: A simple way to handle this is to use some tool that treat tsv etc. as a database and allow sql-like queries to it. Then you can just declare a join condition on `Source` and `Location`. There are several tools like this, one example is [q](https://github.com/harelba/q).

Comment: There are three cases where a variant is on chr16 in your input, but only two in the output, is that intentional? Also, can we assume that the first fields are unique? Those look like protein positions, and you can have multiple variants affecting the same protein position.

Comment: @terdon Yes, that is intentional because the row `ABYY:0001       101    ch1        16` is not swapped--in both files it is on line #5 therefore there is no need to report it when it is unswapped. Regarding 2nd question, yes those are in fact QNAME columns from a SAM/BAM file and they should be unique.

Comment: Ah, right. `ABC` is a HUGO gene name, so I assumed the others were just names I wasn't familiar with, thanks.

Comment: Do your files REALLY start with blanks such that the first column is right-aligned? Doe the other columns also start with blanks such that the data values are centered under the column header names? If not and your data is simply TSV then please fix that in your example.

Comment: @EdMorton that might be my bad, the OP had originally included indicative line numbers at the beginning of each line which did help clarify but added confusion as to whether they were actually part of the file, so I asked that they be removed. But in any case, are there any `awk` flavors (I am assuming you'll be using awk) that would choke on that when not using a non-default `FS`?

Comment: @terdon took me a second to parse `not using a non-default FS` as meaning `using the default FS` (it does, right?) :-). The only problem would be if there could be blank fields or fields that can contain blanks and then we'd have to use `FS="\t"` or similar rather than the default FS. Personally, I'd be using `FS="\t"` in my answer just to be safe if it wasn't for the apparent blanks in the example.

Comment: No, I was thinking that the leading blanks would only be an issue when the `FS` is set to something other than whitespace (so non-default). If we use `FS="\t"` then that would indeed be an issue. I was just wondering if you knew of some obscure `awk` implementation that would choke on leading spaces with the _default_ `FS`. I guess not, thanks!

Comment: No, all awks will ignore leading and trailing white space and treat all other contiguous chains of white space as the field separator with the default FS,

Comment: @paropunam can the same identifier appear with 2 different positions in 1 file? Can the same position appear with 2 different identifiers in 1 file? Do you want to compare the identifier+position between the 2 files or just the identifier or just the position?

Comment: Thank you both. Fantastic answers and discussion. Really helpful! I'm just going through them trying to understand every line. @EdMorton `Identifier` is unique and there shouldn't really be any repetitions. It's extremely unlikely there'd be any repetitions. However, `Position` is not unique at all and there can be a lot of repetitions within the file. If I understand your last question correctly, I actually want the entire row to match, so `Identifier` and `Position` should be both equal among the compared rows to consider the row as swapped within the same `Source` and `Location` combination

Comment: In my experience `It's extremely unlikely there'd be any repetitions` means `there will be repetitions when I least expect it` :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those rare occasions when I'd probably use `getline` due to the size of your input files so we only save a handful of lines in memory at a time instead of >10G:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    print "Group_Source:Location", "df1.index", "df2.index"
}
NR != FNR { exit }
{ srcLoc = $3 ":" $4 }
srcLoc != prevSrcLoc {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        diff()
    }
    prevSrcLoc = srcLoc
}
{
    file1[$1,$2] = FNR - 1
    if ( (getline < ARGV[2]) > 0 ) {
        file2[$1,$2] = FNR - 1
    }
}
END { diff() }

function diff(          idPos) {
    for ( idPos in file1 ) {
        if ( file1[idPos] != file2[idPos] ) {
            print prevSrcLoc, file1[idPos], file2[idPos]
        }
    }
    delete file1
    delete file2
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.tsv file2.tsv
Group_Source:Location   df1.index       df2.index
ch1:16  6       4
ch1:16  4       6
ch1:18  10      9
ch1:18  9       10
ch2:53  17      14
ch2:53  15      17
ch2:53  14      15
```

For more info on `getline`, please read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

The above would work even if an `Identifier` and/or `Position` was repeated within the input since it's comparing all 4 fields between the 2 files. It does assume that the Source and Location values are in the same order between the 2 files as shown in the sample input.

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic answer. It does exactly what I need. Do you have any favorite resources online which you would recommend to better understand this type of awk programming? I'm quite new to awk and having trouble understanding some of the lines, such as `srcLoc != prevSrcLoc {...`.

Comment: Youre welcome. Thats a test comparing the contents of 2 variables, one containing the current Source and Location values from the current input line, the other those values from the previous input line. It's so we can do something (call diff()) when those key values change. Regarding favorite resources - get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to write awk scripts. The author provides an online version for reference but everyone should first buy the book to support his work in providing gawk and the documentation. Then lurk here and in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively straightforward in `awk`. For example:

```
$ awk '{ 
        if(FNR==1){
            next
        }
        else if(FNR==NR){
            a[$1]=FNR-1;
        } 
        else if ( a[$1] != FNR-1 ){
            print $3":"$4, FNR-1, a[$1]
        }
    }' file1.tsv file2.tsv 
ch1:16 4 6
ch1:16 6 4
ch1:18 9 10
ch1:18 10 9
ch2:53 14 17
ch2:53 15 14
ch2:53 17 15
```

#### Explanation

- `if(FNR==1){ next }`: `FNR` holds the line number (record number) of the file currently being read. So if this is the first line of either input file, just skip it since we don't want to process the header.
- `else if(FNR==NR){ ... }`: `NR` holds the current input line number, irrespective of which file is being read. So if `FNR` is equal to `NR`, that means we are reading the first file.
- `a[$1]=FNR-1`: so, if this is the first file, store the first field as an index (key) in an associative array whose value will be the current file's line number (`FNR`), but minus one because we don't want to be counting the header.
- `else if ( a[$1] != FNR-1 ){`: this `else if` is linked to the previous one, so we will only enter this one if `FNR` is not equal to `NR`, so only when we are reading the second file. So, if we are reading the second file *and* the value stored in the `a` array for this line's first field is not equal to the current file's line number minus one, then we want to print.
- `print $3":"$4, FNR-1, a[$1]`: so we print the 3rd field, a `:` and the 4th field, and then the FNR minus one and the value stored in the `a` array for this first field.

Finally, to have it pretty printed with padding and the header, use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
            printf "%-26s%-12s%-12s\n", \
                "Group_Source:Location","df1.index","df2.index"
        } 
        { 
            if(FNR==1){ next }
            else if(FNR==NR){ a[$1]=FNR-1 } 
            else if ( a[$1] != FNR-1){
                printf "%-26s%-12s%-12s\n", $3":"$4, FNR-1, a[$1]
            }
        }' file1.tsv file2.tsv 
Group_Source:Location     df1.index   df2.index   
ch1:16                    4           6           
ch1:16                    6           4           
ch1:18                    9           10          
ch1:18                    10          9           
ch2:53                    14          17          
ch2:53                    15          14          
ch2:53                    17          15
```

---

***Important***: this approach requires you to keep an albeit small amount of data in memory for every line of the first file (bar the header). This could be an issue for huge files, although probably not on most machines where you're likely to do this sort of operation. If this is a problem, I recommend [Ed's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704380/22222) which should both significantly faster and not have any memory issues.

Comment: FWIW I could be wrong but I THINK my answer might be a bit faster than yours rather than a bit slower since the larger the hash table the more collisions and so the slower it gets and with >10G of entries I could imagine that becoming an issue, plus awk has to dynamically allocate memory for the hash table as it grows (probably in blocks) so I could imagine that adding a few cycles as the memory needs increase. I dont really expect much difference in speed of execution either way though.

Comment: @EdMorton you're not wrong at all. I was just investigating this because I was surprised to see that my approach was twice as fast as yours on the OP's data. But that's just because it's a trivial example. When testing on larger files, your approach is an order of magnitude faster! Granted that might be because I made my test data by concatenating the OPs files many times, so there will be a lot of overlap. Nevertheless, it was faster so it's both more memory efficient _and_ faster. Neat!

Comment: I didn't expect a big difference at all. Interesting, thanks for testing it.

Comment: Even if you have tons of memory on a machine, using it when you don't have to mean evicting more useful data from disk cache, making the system slower overall.  (And with more copy/reallocate as a hash table grows, probably some memory bandwidth.)

Comment: FYI I've been chatting with one of the GNU awk developers and apparently, in gawk at least, arrays don't use memory very efficiently and as they grow (and they grow exponentially as they need more memory allocated so as to minimize how many times the reallocation happens) they can end up using huge amounts of memory and require paging which would contribute to the slow down.